# c++ reinitializing static constant members

Tags: c++

I have a class `Worker` and another class `A` with a `static const` private member as in

```cpp
class Worker {
    enum class IMPL {
          LAZY   = 1,
          ACTIVE = 2,
          CRAZY  = 4,
          ...      // omitted for brevity
    };
    Worker(IMPL impl); 
    ...           // omitted for brevity
};

class A {
   private:
     static const Worker worker;
     ...          // omitted for brevity
 };
```

The value of `worker` is set only once in one translation unit and it does not need to change neither across instances of `A` (hence the `static` keyword) nor during the duration of the program (hence the `const` keyword). It is set for example with

```cpp
//somefile.cpp
const auto A::worker = Worker{LAZY};
```

However, there are different possible values for `worker` and writing benchmarking units for them is becoming a bit of a problem. I'd like to benchmark all implementations of the class `A` with different workers. I can write a single benchmarking unit for each element in the enum `IMPL`, it initializes `A` with the appropriate value of `worker` and then it runs. But I need to write a different translation unit containing this initialization and a `main()` entry point for each value in `IMPL`. Is there a way that I can avoid this?

I wouldn't want to make `worker` a variable in `A` since this is performance critical code and that would carry thread-safety issues down the line.

Comment: Could this not be done by making A a template class? Various unit test suits and I suspect benchmark suits are capable of iterating over template arguments.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea, perhaps it will take a bit of reworking in my code though

Comment: Another idea is to add generation of the benchmark tests in the build system (I'm using CMake), it's not nice, but it avoids code duplication and reworking my library